# How to reset widget layout inside a view layout during device rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

Well, i am developing new features inside a product which means lots of limitations i just can't break.

There is one activity which monitor the rotation event but use one unified layout for both portrait and landscape. Now i need to add some animations for several widgets inside the view.

For example, animation A to expand a toolbar, while B to collapse it.

But when i do A in landscape mode, and then rotate to portrait mode, the widgets still keep the position after animation A instead of the original layout configured in the xml file.

So what i want is to reset the layout partially. How can i achieve it???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a solution. Well may be not the best, it still solve my problem.

Insert a parent layout inside the activity view, let's say  and put nothing inside it. 
During the run time, add the child view according to the screen orientation dynamically as following:

Put the codes inside the onConfigurationChanged().

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutId);
View viewPor/viewLand = getLayoutInfalter().Infalte(R.layout.Por/Land, null);
ll.addView(viewPor/viewLand);
```

You may need a object associated with the specific view for manipulating the widgets inside the view for the animations.